# Combine large number of NSArrays into single NSArray in Objective-C or Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsarray

I can combine two NSArrays with the following code:

```
NSArray *combinedArray =firstArray?[firstArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:secondArray]:[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:secondArray];
```

If you have a large number of arrays such as ten or more, is there a simpler way to combine them than one by one?

Comment: Please make up your mind what language you are using. — Your Objective-C code makes no sense. Your use of `alloc-initWithArray` is silly. If you are appending arrays to a single array, you should be using an NSMutableArray. — If you are using Swift you should not have _any_ NSArrays. You should have Swift Arrays of the same type, and then this is trivial.

Comment: It is not harassment to request clarification, nor to point out that in Swift adding multiple arrays is trivial. Also, you cannot "translate" between the way one combines multiple NSArrays in Objective-C and the way one combines multiple Swift arrays in Swift.

Comment: Nothing was "orchestrated". Several people independently voted. That is how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about Swift and all you need it's a short way, then you can do it like this:

```
let a = [0, 1]
let b = [2, 3]
let c = [4, 5]

let d = [a, b, c].flatMap { $0 }
```

Comment: To expand on that, you can even use `.lazy.flatMap { $0 }` to treat the combined elements as a sequence without actually allocating space for and copying all the elements.

Comment: Love flatmap.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[LinqToObjectiveC](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC) may be your help.

This project contains a collection of NSArray and NSDictionary methods that allow you to execute queries using a fluent syntax, inspired by Linq.

I think you can merge ten or more arrays simply like below.

```
id mergedArray = [tenOrMoreArrays linq_aggregate:^id(id item, id aggregate) {
    return [aggregate arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:item];
}];
```

*I have never tried this project, but I think it's worth to try.